# VS2013 Account Sign In "Script Error" The Value of the property 'evt_LoginMobile_onload" is null or undefined

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8.1, I already sign in with my Live ID.

I try to connect to TFS, VS tries to show me login popup but I get a white popup window then a script error popup that says

an error has occurred in the script on this page, it says the value of the property 'evt_LoginMobile_online' is null or undefined, not a function object

Code: 0

URL: https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=https%3a%2f%2faccesscontrol.windows.net%2f&wreply=https%3a%2f%2ftfsprodch1acs01.accesscontrol.windows.net%2fv2%

It asks me if I want to continue running scripts.  When i click yes or no, I still get the same white page and nothing happens.

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this solution solves your problem,

[Troubleshooting connections from Internet Explorer & Visual Studio to Visual Studio Online](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e8fb58cf-35fb-4653-8d00-93f51e7cda31/troubleshooting-connections-from-internet-explorer-visual-studio-to-visual-studio-online?forum=TFService)

Comment: Hi, I am facing a problem which is same as the above problem in developer license sign-in with VS2015. I tried this solution but didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Just update Internet Explorer to the newest version. I updated from version 8 to version 11 and everything went well after that...

IE 11 download link: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/internet-explorer-11-for-windows-7-details.aspx

Comment: Works for VS 2015 too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Microsoft login website URL to trusted sites from IE. Follow the [URL](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135465/how-to-enable-javascript-in-windows) to enable JS and add whatever URL is showing in error popup (here in image it shows as (https://login.live.com/login) open from visual studio to Trusted website, It should work afterwards.